# Drupal 7 Language Switcher

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to customise what languages are available for the website?
Lets say, the 'About page' is in 5 different languages, so the Language switcher will display options for all of the 5 languages. While Home page is only in 2 languages available so the Languages switcher will display only two options, not all 5 as for the About page.

Comment: There are answers for this on Drupal Stackexchange [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/62893/16305).

Answer (score 2):

The language switcher of Drupal adds an extra css class on the untranslated pages language link(s). You can hide those links using CSS.

```
.locale-untranslated { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i remember if installed this module [**Language Switcher Dropdown**](https://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) and page not a translated, language selection does not work or this lang option not wraped in tag < **a** > or some thing like so